# Is there any way to get stack route in react native router flux?

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-native-router-flux

I quite frequently have used `Navigation.reset("PageX")`. Now in few cases it is possible that I have not navigated via that route and it crashes my application.
Also, `Navigation.pop()` is not a solution for me, as I do not want to pop just one screen but remove few screens from my stack and navigate to PageX.

Is there any way through which I can identify if PageX exists in my stack?

I am using "react-native-router-flux" version "4.0.6"

Comment: `Actions.popTo("PageX")` try this?

Answer (score 1):

react-native-router-flux uses named routes. So you might not forget if you have declared that route or not.

**Here's the first screenshot where it is showed how to declare a named route.**
Don't forget to add `type={ActionConst.REPLACE}`.

[image: Here's the first screenshot where it is showed how to declare a named route.]

and when calling that route, you'll have to pass parameter object with `type:'reset'` key value pair.
**Here's the second screenshot where it is showed how to use a named route.**
[image: Here's the second screenshot where it is showed how to use a named route.]

Get more details from the docs here.

> https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API.md